# How do I make combos in Find Mii II?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

In Find Mii II, it mentions that of I have characters that are dressed similarly I can get them to perform combos.

What does "dressed similarly" mean? And how do I actually get them to do the combos? Do I have to press something in particular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When two heroes in a row are wearing similar colors, the same colors, or particular combinations of colors, they can "Create Team" to create a combo attack.  This is the third option under "Attack" and "Magic" in your menu.

When your teammate joins the fight, together they'll have the option to "Combo Attack."  If the colors are similar (ie, light green and dark green, or yellow and orange, pink and red, or purple and blue) they'll simply attack a bit stronger than they would have otherwise.

Here's a video of a "similar color" team in action:

If their colors are the same, they'll be able to do an extra strong version of their standard magic attack instead.  Note that not all of the standard magic attacks are damaging towards enemies - some of them are simply beneficial towards your team.

In certain situations, you'll need to send in a combo of your team to handle a particular obstacle.  These obstacles include:

- Ghost with Shadowlight Shield - Black + White
- Ice or Frozen room - Red + Red
- Poison or Gas - Yellow + Yellow
- Room of Fire - Blue + Blue

There are also a couple of "single specific ally" obstacles:

- Dark room - One white shirt ally
- White/blinding light room - One dark shirt ally

I used a couple of resources to compile this information which you might find useful.  [This guide](http://www.thonky.com/find-mii-3ds/find-mii-ii/), and this [IGN Wiki guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/nintendo-3ds/Find_Mii_II) were among the most beneficial sources of information.

Answer (score 1):

Also note, if you don't have a same or similar Mii next in line, the "combo" option won't be there. Its good to pay attention to the Miis you have going in and use the "return" option sending some to the back of the line to make the most of them.