# What do I do in the poisonous room?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

I keep losing heroes because they can't do anything in the room filled with poison.

What can I do to get past this room? Do I need a certain potion?

Comment: The answer to this is contained in my answer to your [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50111/how-do-i-make-combos-in-find-mii-ii) :)

Comment: Seriously? Awesome. Should we keep this question, then? I am okay with deleting it. :)

Comment: That's your call, it's not a duplicate question.  I suppose you could answer it now that you know the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send in a "Combo" of two heros with yellow shirts.

For more detail, see Agent86's answer at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50128/2262.